# capturar grupos de pattern com regex

Tags: regex

Como faço para capturar informações separadas por grupos com regex?
possuo uma string com o seguinte formato:

```
/+1-541-754-3010 156 Alphand_St. <J Steeve>

 133, Green, Rd. <E Kustur> NY-56423 ;+1-541-914-3010
```

Esta `string` possui 3 informações diferentes:

Primeira `string`:

- telefone (1-541-754-3010)
- nome (J Steeve)
- endereço (156 Alphand St.)

Segunda `string`:

- telefone (1-541-914-3010)
- nome (E Kustur)
- endereço (133 Green Rd. NY-56423)

É possível capturar as 3 informações separadas em grupos de uma vez? Até o momento eu consegui apenas capturar o telefone usando o seguinte `pattern`:

```
(\+(.*?)\s+?)
```

Tentei adicionar grupos em seguida apenas com outro parênteses e não funciona, exemplo:

```
(\+(.*?)\s+?)(\<(.*?)\>)
```

O `pattern` acima acaba selecionando o telefone junto ao endereço.

Comment: Vc está usando alguma linguagem específica? Os campos sempre estão neste formato? (nome com inicial e sobrenome, entre `<>`; telefone +1-123-123-1234, etc). Na segunda string, o endereço está com 2 pedaços (o nome está entre a rua e o CEP, pelo que entendi), é isso mesmo?

Comment: Uma ideia seria capturar o telefone e o nome com regex, depois fazer um replace removendo essas informações, o que sobrar é o endereço.

Comment: @Sam Tentei fazer uma solução mais geral, mas no fim estava ficando complicada demais. Acho que a sua ideia é a solução mais simples, inclusive comentei isso na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/343431/112052) :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo as strings são essas mesmas, o nome sempre estarã em `<nome>` e o telefone sempre começa com `+`

Comment: a linguagem que estou usando é `Go`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema de usar `.` é que ele corresponde a qualquer caractere, e por isso é abrangente demais e pode acabar pegando partes da string que você não quer.

O melhor é [dizer exatamente o que você quer](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want). No caso do telefone, se ele sempre está no formato indicado, use:

```
(\+\d-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})
```

Ou seja, o sinal de `+`, seguido de um dígito (`\d`), traço, 3 dígitos (`\d{3}`), traço, 3 dígitos, traço, 4 dígitos.
O número depois do `+` é o DDI, e [vários países têm códigos com mais de um dígito](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_c%C3%B3digos_telef%C3%B3nicos). Então talvez seja interessante mudar o início para `\+\d{1,3}`: o sinal de `+` seguido de um, dois ou três dígitos (`{1,3}` significa "entre uma e três ocorrências").

Só que se o DDI for do Brasil, por exemplo, então os telefones não têm esse formato (`123-123-1234`). Mas aí já estou especulando, porque você só deu exemplos com DDI igual a 1, então vamos manter assim.

Com isso o telefone não será confundido com nenhum outro trecho da string.

---

O mesmo vale para os outros campos. O nome, por exemplo. Caso ele sempre esteja entre `<` e `>`, podemos usar `<(.*?)>` como você fez. Só que o ponto (`.`) significa "qualquer caractere", então se a string tiver `<@!#$>`, a regex aceita e considera que `@!#$` é o nome. E como `*` significa "**zero** ou mais ocorrências", isso quer dizer que a string pode ter inclusive `<>`, e o nome será vazio.

Se o nome sempre for "Letra maiúscula, espaço, letras", você pode usar `<([A-Z] [A-Z][a-z]+)>`, por exemplo.

Os colchetes (`[]`) indicam uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): eles servem para indicar que você quer qualquer caractere que esteja dentro deles.
Por exemplo, `[abc]` significa "a letra `a` **ou** a letra `b` **ou** a letra `c`" (**apenas uma delas**, qualquer uma serve). É uma expressão que corresponde a apenas **um** caractere.

Dentro dos colchetes também é possível usar atalhos como `A-Z`, que significa "letras de `A` a `Z`" (ou seja, qualquer letra maiúscula). Então `[A-Z] [A-Z][a-z]+` significa:

- uma letra maiúscula seguida de espaço: `[A-Z]`
- uma letra maiúscula (`[A-Z]`) seguida uma ou mais letras minúsculas (`[a-z]+`)

Só que isso não considera caracteres acentuados (`á`, `ñ`, `õ`, etc).

Se quiser ser mais abrangente, você pode usar as [categorias Unicode](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) (se a linguagem/engine que você está usando suporta este recurso).

Eu posso usar a categoria `Ll`, que considera qualquer letra minúscula (incluindo caracteres gregos, cirílicos e muitos outros, [a lista é grande](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ll/list.htm)), e a categoria `Lu` para letras maiúsculas ([cuja lista também é grande](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/list.htm)).
Então a regex ficaria `<(\p{Lu} \p{Lu}\p{Ll}+)>`.

Se não quiser pegar tantos caracteres e se limitar ao alfabeto latino, pode incluir os caracteres acentuados nos colchetes, como por exemplo `[A-ZÁÂÃÉÊÍÎÓÔÕÚÛÇ]` para letras maiúsculas (inclua todos que precisar nos colchetes).

Enfim, escolha o que encaixar melhor nos seus casos de uso. Se as entradas forem bem controladas e não há chance de ter strings como `$   @123` no lugar do nome, até mesmo `.*?` é aceitável. Quanto mais precisa é a regex, mais complexa ela fica, porém quanto mais simples, maior é a chance de falsos positivos.

Obs: Não tenho certeza se no Go, os caracteres `<` e `>` precisam ser escapados para `\<` e `\>`.

---

Outro problema está na ordem em que as informações estão, que pelos exemplos dados, parece variar:

- na primeira linha temos telefone, endereço e nome
- na segunda linha temos parte do endereço, nome, outra parte do endereço (CEP) e telefone

Uma alternativa seria ter uma regex com alternância (usando `|`), ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
(?:(telefone) (endereço) (nome))|(?:(parte_endereço) (nome) (parte2_endereço) (telefone))|(?:....)
```

No caso, `telefone` seria a expressão acima (`\+\d...`), idem para `nome` e `endereço` (que não chegamos a abordar em detalhes, mas teria a sua própria expressão colocada ali).

Para cada alternância, coloca-se uma ordem em que as informações podem estar. O problema é que isso faz com que tenhamos que repetir a mesma expressão várias vezes. Além disso você teria que verificar qual grupo que deu o *match*: o telefone pode estar no primeiro ou no sétimo grupo, por exemplo (os parênteses mais externos não entram na contagem porque eu coloquei `?:`, e isso faz com que eles [não sejam considerados grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap)).

**Se** a linguagem/engine que você está usando suporta [sub-rotinas de regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) (também chamados de padrões recursivos), é possível usá-las para aproveitar a mesma expressão em outros pontos da regex.
A ideia da subrotina é reaproveitar a expressão de um dos parênteses em outro ponto da regex. Por exemplo:

```
(telefone) (endereço) (nome)|((?2)) ((?3)) ((?1))
```

A expressão `(?1)` significa "a mesma expressão que está no primeiro grupo de captura". E como um grupo de captura é definido pelos parênteses, então `(telefone)` é o primeiro grupo, e `(?1)` é apenas um atalho para não repetirmos a mesma expressão (`\+\d-etc...`). Note que coloquei entre parênteses: `((?1))`. Isso faz com que ela se torne **outro** grupo de captura, ou seja, é possível capturar caso a string seja encontrada neste ponto (e ela será o sexto grupo de captura, já que é o sexto par de parênteses da expressão).

Veja [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/WwWnqm/1/) um exemplo de como ficaria.

Mas infelizmente não são todas as linguagens e bibliotecas que implementam esta funcionalidade. Uma que conheço é o [módulo regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) do Python (não é o mesmo que o módulo `re`, pois ele adiciona várias funcionalidades, incluindo as sub-rotinas). E pelo que vi na [documentação do Go](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), ele não suporta a sintaxe `(?1)`, então o jeito é repetir a mesma expressão várias vezes.

Outra alternativa é fazer [como sugeriu o @Sam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/343378/capturar-grupos-de-pattern-com-regex#comment691830_343378): você pode extrair o nome e telefone (usando as expressões já explicadas acima), e em seguida faz uma substituição removendo-os da string. O que sobrar é o endereço.